# How to handle nginx redirect to a mounted Rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx

I have a rails 4 application with an engine mounted on a seperate domain like so:

```
mount Test::Engine => '/', as: 'test', constraints: { domain: 'test_engine.com' }
```

The application itself is hosted on a DigitalOcean droplet. It uses a different domain, say `application.com`

I need several domains (test_domain1.com, test_domain2.com) to also open the rails engine.
I imagined I would achieve this by configuring all domain DNS A records (bots naked domains and www.*) to point to droplet IP and have nginx redirect them to `test_engine.com`.

The gist of nginx.conf is:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name test_domain1.com www.test_domain1.com test_domain2.com www.test_domain2.com;
  return 307  https://test_engine.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name application.com www.application.com;
  return 307  https://application.com$request_uri;
}
```

Unfortunately, the redirect does not seem to work properly, for example, visiting `www.test_domain1.com` I end up at `https://application.com` instead of `https://test_engine.com`

I realize this is very specific and a better solution may be possible.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You want 301 not 307.  Is that just a typo on posting here?

Comment: 301 would set permanent redirect, breaking easy testing. 307<->301 has no bearing on function,

Comment: Have you tested with curl/wget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using regex matching for server names a-la

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ~test_domain;
  return 307  https://test_engine.com$request_uri;
}
```

and **hard-restarting nginx** with `sudo service nginx restart` instead of `sudo service nginx reload`.